# Losing decimal places when accessing key

Tags: python, decimal

I have a list of tuples, and now I need to get the key `rate`

```
'rate': 3.3000000000000003
```

However when I do `print rates[0]['rate']` I am getting `3.3`, not `3.3000000000000003`. Any idea why, and how to solve?

Comment: depends on where you print it

Comment: The minimal example for this is `print 3.3000000000000003`. You're not losing any information, it's just a representation.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, ok, but how to represent the number with all decimal places?  I need this in terms of visual representation, I can't truncate info.

Comment: `print repr(3.3000000000000003)`. Or be more explicit about the formatting you want using e.g. `str.format` to create a string to print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not loosing the precision. Python is just changing it's *representation* by making precision. If you want to display the value as it is, you may use [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr) as:

```
print repr(rates[0]['rate'])
```

which will print your number as a string:

```
'3.3000000000000003'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Don’t confuse rounding with formatting a value for output.** If your goal is simply to output a numerical value with a certain number of decimal places, you don’t typically need to use round(). Instead, just specify the desired precision when formatting. For example:

```
>>> x = 1.23456
>>> format(x, '0.2f')
'1.23'
>>> format(x, '0.3f')
'1.235'
>>> 'value is {:0.3f}'.format(x)
'value is 1.235'
>>>
```

Also, resist the urge to round floating-point numbers to "fix" perceived accuracy problems. For example, you might be inclined to do this:

```
>>> a = 2.1
>>> b = 4.2
>>> c = a + b
>>> c
6.300000000000001
>>> c = round(c, 2)      # "Fix" result (???)
>>> c
6.3
>>>
```

**[Source](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000393/ch03.html#_discussion_41)**

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can use string formatting tools, as @parik and @Molnuddin hoted. Also you can use decimal arithmetic module `decimal` for operations for [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) or [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) .